# Flutter Odd Text Display

Tags: flutter

I updated flutter yesterday (May 7th) and getting some odd behavior.  With the following two classes I would expect to get a simple screen with a white background and a vertical list of 4 words.  I would also expect the text to have no formatting/styling, so small, black letters.  Instead I get the image below...

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_caddie/ui/OverlayWidget.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Base',
      home: OverlayWidget(),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my OverlayWidget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OverlayWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: BottomScrollingList(BottomScrollingList.getDataList()));
  }
}

class BottomScrollingList extends StatelessWidget {
  List<Data> dataList;

  BottomScrollingList(this.dataList);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: dataList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Text("${dataList[index].name}");
        });
  }

  static List<Data> getDataList() {
    List<Data> dataList = List();
    dataList.add(Data("CEO"));
    dataList.add(Data("Manager"));
    dataList.add(Data("Supervisor"));
    dataList.add(Data("Peon"));
    return dataList;
  }
}

class Data {
  Data(this.name);

  String name;
}
```

[image]

Comment: you need a `Scaffold` as a `home: ...` (i mean `MaterialApp` should have `Scaffold` child, not `OverlayWidget`)

Comment: Thank you!  I never would have dreamed the image I attached would be the default style...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your `Container` inside a `Scaffold` widget.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a `Scaffold` widget.
Code:-

```dart
...

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Base',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: OverlayWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }

  ...

}

...
```